# Ist "Es weiß ich" gutes Deutsch?

Tags: pronoun, personal-pronoun

I know *Das weiß ich* works

And also *Ich weiß es*

So what is the reason you can't start the sentence with the pronoun "es"?

Comment: Es weiss ich is grammatically incorrect as I know, you can't start a sentence with a dummy object *es*

Comment: What is the reason you can't start a sentence with a dummy object?

Comment: @MrsRona it is by no means clear we have a dummy object here. Consider: „ich weiß nicht wo der Hammer liegt. Weißt du es?“ Besides many linguists are fighting over the dummy object. You have fallen prey to the rigid rules of grammar books for foreigners. I delete my answer for the moment to protect it from irresponsible voters.

Comment: @Ludi But I haven't got the chance to read your answer

Comment: Thanks, I am done. What @MrsRona says sounds interesting though, I would like to know the reason for this rule he/she mentioned

Comment: @Tomas one reason for this rule which definitely does not apply here is the following! Consider a case with a **real** dummy object: „Er läßt es krachen“, an Idiom. If I regroup this into: „Es läßt er krachen“ it’s still grammatically correct, although highly constructed (er hat ein Tischlein, das er haßt, es läßt er krachen wann’s ihm paßt, die anderen Tische pflegt er) but not as the idiom, because it stresses es, es cannot be a dummy so it must have a different meaning, contrasting es with something. That’s why generally we cannot pull real dummies in front.

Comment: @MrsRona "Es läuft heute wieder gut" or "Es ist gutes Wetter" are valid sentences that start with "es".

Comment: @Robert das sind Subjekte, keine Objekte. Ihr (MrsRonas) Argument ist aber dennoch falsch, weil es kein dummy ist.

Answer (score 4):

> Was ist hier kaputt? — <s>Es weiß ich.</s> Ich weiß es.

but e.g.

> Passiert sowas öfters? — Es kommt vor.

So it's not about a dummy object not leading the sentence, as suggested in the comments. It's rather a dummy object **never thrusts the real subject aside.**

Comment: So Mrsona is right then? Is it a rule?

Comment: Yes, it's a rule.

Comment: @Janka aber wieso möchtet ihr dieses es als dummy klassifizieren? Es kann doch -anders als bei „es regnet“ sehr wohl eine semantische Funktion haben! Auch kann ich das *es* dieser Art bei anderen Verben sehr wohl an den Anfang stellen, etwa so: „Warum bringst du das Bannschwert mit und nicht auch seinen Träger? Es kenne ich, den Träger nicht!“

Comment: Diese Wortstellung ist nur mit dichterischer Freiheit zu rechtfertigen.

Comment: @Janka sie klingt in der Tat poetisch oder geschwollen, aber sie ist grammatisch richtig. Hier müssen wir das falsche vom stilistisch ungewöhnlichen trennen!

Comment: The *es* in *Ich weiß es* is not a dummy object as it refers to what is broken. So the rule is: A object *es* (**not dummy**) cannot be in first position. Because you only put an object in first position if it's important, and if something is important you use a demonstrative pronoun, not *es*.

Comment: Es kommt vor includes no dummy *object*.

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer clear: in all but fringe cases „No!“

The question is not as hard as it may at first appear. The neutral way would be to start with the subject, just like in English:

> Ich weiß es/I know it

If you diverge from this pattern, it is because you want to stress an element other than the subject. Let’s say the object. Consider this traditional advice against lightning bolts!

> Eichen sollst du weichen, Buchen sollst du suchen/Oaks you shall avoid, beeches you shall seek.

Both in German and English, the object is brought to the forth, so as to underscore it and thereby the distinction! **While grammar does not forbid doing that in your example sentence (see addendum), it sounds more than a little weird and there are better alternatives!** Why? Because *es* doesn’t transport a lot of meaning. If you want to stress it, you might additionally replace it by a **demonstrative pronoun**. Hence, the more idiomatic choice:

> Das weiß ich!

```
Much like we prefer „that I know!“ over „it I know!“
```

---

#### Addendum on why dummy objects mentioned in comments  do not apply here

Dummy pronouns  are very hairy animals, of which even the classic cases “es regnet, es schneit...” have been [disputed](http://www.dietz-und-daf.de/GD_DkfA/Gramminfo/txt_MII1/es%20(Info).pdf) in their nature as dummies. If I am forced to include them in my reasoning, I will go by the definition:

> a pronoun used to fulfill the syntactical requirements without providing explicit meaning.

In the case in question we have no indication that *es* carries no meaning. Consider the exchange:

> Weißt du wo der Hammer liegt?
>
> Ich weiß es!

Es has a meaning and points to „wo der Hammer liegt“, that’s why we cannot  omit it in this context. But *es* doesn’t only fulfill syntactic requirements, because in other contexts Germans indeed accept omission:

> Ich weiß!

This places the *es* here in a different category than the es in „es regnet, es dämmert, es tagt“(dummy subjects), which are all rendered ungrammatical by removing *es*, or in “er läßt es sich gut gehen”(dummy object) **Conclusion 1: This type of *es* is not a dummy!**

Furthermore, if I were to replace *wissen* by *kennen* I can immediately invent valid sentences to refute the claims in the comments.

> Warum zog er das Kind hinzu?
>
> *Es* kannte er, den Vater nicht.

Yes, it is a very rare case and sounds poetic, but it is absolutely correct. It is as correct as Schiller’s phrase

> ihn schlugen die Häscher in Bande

It is only due to the better alternative of the demonstrative pronoun that this type of construction with *es* has come to sound very awkward.
Thereby we see, that unless we want specific rules for different very similar verbs, **Conclusion 2: we cannot propound any arguments against this type of *es* in the front.** The grammar in its full, native complexity does not forbid this. It is just overeagerness to describe everything by the rules one knows, which lead to contrary claims!

### On comment by OP: Why this rule with the dummy object

This rule about not pulling **real dummy objects** to the front （see [here](http://www.dietz-und-daf.de/GD_DkfA/Gramminfo/txt_MII1/es%20(Info).pdf), page 2) probably originated precisely from the fact that non dummy *es* as discussed above is correct. Consider the idiom:

> Er läßt es krachen

We cannot pull es to the front without stressing it. If we stress it, it cannot be a dummy, which by definition carries no meaning. However the following highly constructed verse is grammatically correct: „er hat ein Tischlein, das er haßt, es läßt er krachen wann’s ihm paßt, die anderen Tische pflegt er“.

Comment: "While grammar does not forbid doing that in your example sentence" It does forbid, you can't use a dummy object in the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: @MrsRona es is not a dummy here. See the edit!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely happy with some of the other responses/comments here. Generally speaking, it would indeed be quite natural if the example sentence worked. The immediate reason why this is not the case is that *es* behaves somewhat out of the norm.

See *Hans-Werner Eroms*, Syntax der deutschen Sprache, 2000, p. 358 (boldface added):

> Alle Ergänzungen sind vorfeldfähig, und zwar in so gut wie allen morphologischen Formen. Es gibt nur ganz wenige Restriktionen. **So lässt sich das Pronomen *es* nicht in das Vorfeld plazieren.**

["Vorfeldfähig" refers to the ability of a sentence element to be placed in the position ahead of the finite verb (= Vorfeld), i.e., in your example, ahead of *weiß*. *Eroms* points out the case of *es*, which, exceptionally, lacks this ability.]

*Peter Gallmann* in Duden, Die Grammatik, 8th ed. 2009, recital 1382, points out, slightly more broadly, that the following elements either cannot or can only under limited circumstances, appear in the Vorfeld (boldface added):

> Schwach betonte Personal- und Reflexivpronomen, außer als Subjekt.
> **Insbesondere erscheint das Pronomen *es* praktisch nur als Subjekt**
> **oder Platzhalter im Vorfeld.** Beispiel mit *es* als Objekt:
>
> *[Es] weißt [du] [ganz genau]. (Stattdessen:) [Das] weißt [du] [ganz genau]. (Oder:) [Du] weißt [es] [ganz genau].

<sub>Bonus track: If you are really interested in learning *why* this is so, I would submit that this appears to be a question more suitable for a research project than for a thread on this site. That being said, *Eroms* conjectures it might have something to do with a desire to avoid ambiguity:</sub>

> <sub>Der Grund dafür kann vielleicht darin erblickt werden, dass im Vorfeld
> nur das expletive *es* oder das pronominale *es* als Subjekt stehen kann.
> Mögliche Ambiguitäten werden auf diese Weise blockiert.</sub>

<sub>Another explanation is offered by *Gisela Zifonun et al.*, Grammatik der deutschen Sprache, vol. 2, 1997, p. 1584:</sub>

> <sub>Es scheint also keine rein strukturellen Gründe für die
> Nicht-Vorfeldfähigkeit von akkusativischem *es* zu geben; der Grund ist
> wohl am ehesten darin zu sehen, daß hier eine so schwach ausgeprägte
> Form in einer - wenn auch relativ gering - markierten syntaktischen
> Funktion, als Akkusativkomplement, auftritt. Das heißt, eine
> strukturell markierte Einheit braucht offensichtlich auch ein gewisses
> Minimum an morphologischer und phonetischer "Substanz", um an
> exponierter Stelle  am Satzanfang stehen zu können.</sub>